# roscpp node handles convention

Tags: ros, node-handle, nodes, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know what is the convention for creating ROS node handles. I have my ROS nodes, but I realized that for every subscriber/publisher in my node I have created an individual node handle.

I am doing this in one node/program, for example:

```
ros::NodeHandle motor_nh;
ros::NodeHandle velocity_nh;
ros::NodeHandle vel_callback_nh;
ros::NodeHandle imu_nh;
ros::NodeHandle alarm_sound_nh;
```

I am not sure if that is the correct usage, or am I supposed to have one single node handle for the entire node/program?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192420/roscpp-node-handles-convention/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2014-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the same node handle for all of your publishers and subscribers.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-09-10**:
You basically already use one node handle because all your variables are effectively using the same instance behind the scene.